# Ignoring log configuration

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging

A project having this pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This test in `src/test/java/foobar/Test.java`:

```
package foobar;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class Test {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(Test.class);

    public void testMe() {
        LOG.info("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and this `src/test/resources/logging.properties`:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=Hello %1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n
```

Then, calling

```
mvn clean install -Djava.util.logging.config.file=src/test/resources/logging.properties
```

Prints

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running foobar.Test
Hello 2017-10-06 16:30:19 INFO foobar.Test testMe Hello World
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.013 sec
```

I see the **Hello** and the **Hello World**.

If I change the dependency to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The `logging.properties`-File is ignored. And the output changes to

```
-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Running foobar.Test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
```

How to order slf4j to use JUL?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, i need a additional dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```